# Print all elements in <li> - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am web-scraping with `Python` and `BeautifulSoup`.

I need to scrape this

```
<li class="review-rating">
   <h5 class="review-rating__title">Location:</h5>
   <span class="review-rating__score">5</span>
   <h5 class="review-rating__title">Value:</h5>
   <span class="review-rating__score">3</span>
   <h5 class="review-rating__title">Facilities:</h5>
   <span class="review-rating__score">4</span>
   <h5 class="review-rating__title">Service:</h5>
   <span class="review-rating__score">4</span>
   <h5 class="review-rating__title">Cleanliness:</h5>
   <span class="review-rating__score">5</span>
</li>
```

I have actually scraped this markup with this code

```
for scores_of_this_customer in tt.select('li.review-rating'):
   print(scores_of_this_customer.select('h5.review-rating__title')[0].text +" "+scores_of_this_customer.select('span.review-rating__score')[0].text)
```

But this prints only `Location: 5`

I want a way to print all those scores by using a Loop.

I know I can print other Scores by indexing them as `[1]`,`[2]`... and so on but I don't want to write 5 print statements

**PS:**

This code worked for me.

```
if tt.select('li.review-rating'):
      soup = tt.select('li.review-rating').find("li", {"class", "review-rating"})
      keys = soup.findAll("h5", {"class" : "review-rating__title"})
      values = soup.findAll("span", {"class" : "review-rating__score"})
      for key, value in zip(keys, values):
       print(key.text + ": " + value.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is possible to access them directly. Try this:

```
import urllib
import bs4
url = "http://yourURL.com"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
```

If you really need only this `<li class="review-rating">` results, you can put uncomment the following part:

```
# soup = soup.find("li", {"class", "review-rating"})
```

Then the next part should nicely go through all the key / value combinations:

```
keys = soup.findAll("h5", {"class" : "review-rating__title"})
values = soup.findAll("span", {"class" : "review-rating__score"})
for key, value in zip(keys, values):
    print(key.text + ": " + value.text)
```

This code worked for OP:

```
if tt.select('li.review-rating'):
      soup = tt.select('li.review-rating').find("li", {"class", "review-rating"})
      keys = soup.findAll("h5", {"class" : "review-rating__title"})
      values = soup.findAll("span", {"class" : "review-rating__score"})
      for key, value in zip(keys, values):
       print(key.text + ": " + value.text)
```

Comment: I'm curious. Is there a way to see the URL you're scraping? It's kind of guesswork.

Comment: I have edited your answer and added the code that worked for me